# forEach and NodeList

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is loosely based on one of W3_School samples:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Hello World!</p>
<p>The DOM is very useful!</p>
<p>This example demonstrates forEach() function</p>

<script>
var x=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"));
x.forEach(function(value, index)
  { 
  document.write(value.innerHTML);
  document.write("<br>");
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if any improvements need (could) be done to the script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only purpose of this script appears to be to illustrate the use the `Array.prototype.slice.call` "idiom" and the `forEach` function. So it's hard to make "improvements" when the purpose of the code isn't its actual result (which is trivial).

What the code actually *does* can be done in a number of ways, some of which won't (directly) use `forEach` and/or `NodeList` and/or `slice.call`. In that case, is it still an improvement? Conversely, sticking to `forEach` etc. doesn't leave much room for change, since the code seems designed as a minimal example of those things.

I'm hesitant to write any code, because I'm not sure what the point would be.

With that said,

- Don't rely on W3 Schools ([this site](http://www.w3fools.com/) lists several reasons and better alternatives)
- Avoid `document.write()` - or use it with open eyes (see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/167996))
- I'd also avoid `forEach` in favor of a standard `for` loop, since `forEach` is not universally supported in browsers (see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=foreach))
- The page's text appears to betray some confusion. Yes, the DOM is useful, and yes, the code demonstrates `forEach`. But `forEach` isn't part of the DOM. The whole point is that a `NodeList` object is a DOM object and not a normal array. It must therefore be converted to one by way of `Array.prototype.slice.call`. *Then* one can use `forEach` which is an array function but which, in and of itself, has nothing to do with the DOM.

---

Update after reading @PM77-1's comment:

There's nothing inherently wrong with this code. It is true, that
A) `for...in` doesn't behave like it does in Java and shouldn't be used here, and that
B) `getElementsByTagName` doesn't return a "real" array. The `slice.call` trick is indeed the "standard" way of converting an "array-like" object (which you find a lot of, unfortunately) to a real array. A very useful trick to know.

So all in all, the code is basically fine. Yes, improvements can be made, [as @Palacsint points out in his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44529/foreach-and-nodelist/44532#44534), but there's nothing terrible going on.

However, while a `NodeList` object isn't a real array, one can still use a regular old `for` loop:

```
var nodes, i;

nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(i = 0 ; i < nodes.length ; i++) {
  document.write(nodes[i].innerHTML);
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

This removes the need for the `slice.call` trick, and it works on old browsers (where `forEach` doesn't exist).

In general, though, when working with the DOM, it's useful to use a library to iron out the otherwise frustrating differences between browsers. jQuery is the king of the hill these days, and with that, you'd do something like this to find and iterate over some elements:

```
$("p").each(function () {
  document.write(this.innerHTML);
  document.write("<br>");
});
```

(Of course, jQuery also makes it easy to do "proper" DOM insertion without resorting to `document.write`, but this is just for illustration)

However, I do think it very wise to learn the nitty-gritty of JS, and not just run straight for jQuery or its ilk. And dealing with those "array-like" is one of those nitty-gritty things indeed.

Comment: It was actually my first `JavaScript` code. Originally I wanted to use `for-in` (assuming that it's similar to one in Java) instead of the *regular* `for` loop in one of W3 samples. After I realized that it's a completely different animal and does not iterate through a collection, I tried to apply `forEach()` function to the return of `getElementsByTagName()` assuming (wrongly again) that it returns an array. At the end I had to use `Array.prototype.slice.call` to convert the list to array.  The resulting code looks somewhat convoluted, so I asked this question.

Comment: @PM77-1 Well, your code is about as good as it gets given what you aimed for. I know it looks convoluted, but, well, that's because the DOM is an odd beast. I've added some more to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Just two minor notes to add *@Flambino*'s great answer:

1. Instead of `x` use intention-revealing names. What's the purpose of this variable? Name according to that. `paragraphs` would be a better name here, it explains the purpose of the variable and avoids mental mapping (readers/maintainers don't have to decode it every time). (It's just a minor thing here, everyone has one slot of short-term memory for `x` but having a couple of abbreviations in a larger project could make understanding code really hard.)

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Use Intention-Revealing Names*, p18; *Avoid Mental Mapping*, p25)
2. [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) founds one error and at least one warning. You could fix those by setting a `title` and an encoding:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>DOM test page</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
   ...
   ```